# How to reduce/remove smell when cooking salmon fin soup?

Tags: soup, tomatoes, smell, salmon

I usually use simple recipes for salmon fin soup (tomato soup + salmon fin with some seasoning mostly). It tastes good but the smell of salmon fin is not.

What should I do to reduce or remove the smell?

Comment: Can you elaborate more? Do you mean the fishy smell?

Comment: I normally use ginger or lemon to keep away the fishy smell, but I will need to know what other ingredients/ seasoning you are using and how you prepare your salmon in order to give you advice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Yes it's the fishy smell. I think lemon should work  since there're just tomatoes and some salt/pepper.